# Retrieving data from database to display user profile information using room

Tags: java, android, database, android-studio, android-room

I have set up a login and signup system but I need a profile page to print the information of that user and I am struggling with it. So far I have created the page and where I want it all to be printed. The code I have so far is:

```
package com.example.moneymanagment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import com.example.moneymanagment.models.Users;

public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView name, surname, email, expenditure, leftover;
    private Users users;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_activity);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        users = (Users) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Users");

        name = findViewById(R.id.tvFname);
        surname = findViewById(R.id.tvSname);
        email = findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
        expenditure = findViewById(R.id.tvExpenditure);
        leftover = findViewById(R.id.leftover);

        if (users != null) {
            name.setText(users.getName());
            surname.setText(users.getLastName());
            email.setText(users.getEmail());
        }else {
            name.setText(users.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

After testing it, I have found that it is not meeting the if condition; the user is currently at null despite me logging in. I have another activity in my project that displays the user's name after the login and I used that code as a reference but it does not seem to work.

Please let me know if you need more information. 
Thanks, guys

Comment: You mentioned Room but I didn't saw you using ```room```.  Mentioned Error as well what the actual problem are you facing. Facing Serialization problem or want to know how to fetch data from room using query

Comment: Thank you for replying, I basically need the stored variables in my Users database to be printed out into this activity.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Users class implementing Serializable? It must do so in order to deserialize the "Users" extra from the intent

Comment: Thank you for replying. To be honest I do not think i have done that and I am not sure how to either

Comment: Should be something like class Users implements Serializable, that's it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to know how to use Room to store the Users data. This is all on the android developers website. [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) you can see how to use Room in your project. And [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) you can see some resources that will help you to better understand how to use Room database. They explained it really well, but if you have any doubts you can ask me and I will try to help you. I used Room to make a database with more than 10 tables so I have research the topic a lot in the last few months